# How to use NPM packages with existing C#/MVC project for git-deployment on Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, npm, webpack

I have a fairly large .Net MVC application. Servers side code is all C#, and I have tonnes of client side TS. All my JS libs are in the Scripts directory, most put there by Nuget packages. All my JS is bundled using System.Web.Optimization.ScriptBundles.

My application is deployed via Git to Azure.

I would like to switch everything to using NPM. I have NPM setup, and all the necessary models installed. Is the best to change my ScriptBundle to reference the scripts out of the node_modules folder now? Obviously node_modules is not part of the project, so will those files get copied over in the azure deployment?

I will be adding a mobile (single-page-app) version of the site (in same project) using Webpack to bundle the JS. Could I also use webpack to bundle up the JS for the MVC app?

Thanks,
~S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to use git deployment and move all modules to an npm-repository and then deploy to azure web apps, right?

Azure Web Apps have an open source runtime running under the hood that is called Kudu. Kudu is responsible to fetch and pull your source once the webhook notified it about a new push.

As soon as kudu pulls your source it starts compilation and deployment. Good thing to know, is that kudu provides hooks to change the build and deployment pipeline. You can for example run npm install.

You can read about kudu and the extensibility here:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script

You should be able to find there all information you need.

Comment: Yeah I am already using a custom-deployment-script to run my migrations. My question is about how I should bundle my JS up.

Comment: well basically you just restore your npm packages upon deployment and, yes reference all the JS to use the npm modules. You can also use webpack, you just need to make sure to load the JS from the right directory